# Why don't the two pointer values be the same?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, casting

Quoting Effective C++, Scott Meyer, 3rd Edition , Item 27

```
class Base { ... };
class Derived: public Base { ... };
Derived d;
Base *pb = &d; // implicitly convert Derived* ⇒ Base*
```

> Here we’re just creating a base class pointer to a derived class
>   object,
>   **but sometimes, the two pointer values will not be the same.** When that’s the case, an offset is applied at runtime to the Derived*
>   pointer to get the correct Base* pointer value.

Why are the two pointer values not the same? If it is because how the child and parent objects are laid out in the memory, then how does downcast work later?

Comment: Where is the evidence?

Comment: @EdHeal: Question to me?

Comment: Please make clear which part is the quote and which part is yours.

Comment: Yes - that is the point of comments - clariffication

Comment: @whomever - Why the close flag given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This always happen when using multiple inheritance.

```
class Base1 { int a; };
class Base2 { double b };
class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 { ... };

Derived d;
Base1* pb1 = &d;
Base2* pb2 = &d;
```

Now `&d` cannot possibly be equal to *both* `pb1` and `pb2`, because otherwise `pb1` would equal `pb2`, which is not possible, because two different non-empty objects of unrelated types must occupy different regions of memory. So in at least one case a non-zero offset must be applied.

In most implementations with single inheritance the offset is zero, but the standard does not mandate that.

Indeed, a typical implementation would simply lay out the base object at the beginning of the derived object:

```
 ++-----++
 ||Base ||
 |+-----+|
 |Derived|
 +-------+
```

But when there are more than one base, only one can go at the beginning:

```
 ++-----++
 ||Base1||
 |+-----+|
 ||Base2||
 |+-----+|
 |Derived|
 +-------+
```

The downcast works because the offset is fixed and known at compile time, so there's no problem to apply it when either upcasting or downcasting.

An exception to this is virtual inheritance. For a virtual base the offset is not known at compile time. Typically, the derived object contains an internal hidden pointer to its virtual base, so the upcast can work. But the base doesn't know where its derived object is, so the downcast cannot work, and is not allowed by the language.

Comment: Are you sure - please check!

Comment: I think the code is supposed to say `Base1` and `Base2` for the declarations of `pb1` and `pb2` respectively.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes, fixed.

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, checked.

Comment: Please post the two values `pb1` and `pb2`

Comment: @EdHeal Consider the case where `Base` is laid out after `Derived.`

Comment: @EdHeal I cannot post values for all possible cases, but [here's one](http://ideone.com/4F5KGS).

Comment: Where does `base1` and `base2` come in? Not `base`

Comment: @EdHeal I don't understand your question.

Comment: In the OP it does not mention `base1`

Comment: @n.m. My compiler gives both pb1 and pb2 same value.

Comment: @InQusitive Which compiler and compiler flags? Can you show the code?

Comment: I still do not understand why you conjured up "base1" etc.

Comment: @EdHeal It is an example of a base class pointer being different from a derived class pointer. Since they will not differ in the OP's example. I have provided an example of where they do differ. The example is by necessity different from OP's, bit it still is an example of a base class pointer being different from a derived class pointer. I don't think I can explain it any more clearly so please don't ask me to do that.

Comment: You example inherits from two classes - his inherits from one, So, pray tell, are these the same

Comment: @EdHeal Please don't ask me ay more questions. I have no idea how to explain anything to you. Sorry.

Comment: @n.m. I am using g++ compiler in Ubuntu. I used your code and just added cout<<pb1 and cout<<pb2. Even I was expecting it to be different since both should point to the start of corresponding class. But same address is printed. What does this suggest?

Comment: Please post the exact code you are using. If by any chance your base classes are empty, add a data member to each and try again.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a single inheritance tree that is polymorphic, compilers require each object to begin with a VMT (virtual method table). If base class is polymorphic, the pointer values would match. But ff your base class is non-polymorphic and your derived class is polymorphic, the base class does not introduce the VMT, it is introduced by the very first polymorphic class down the tree. The VMT would be inserted before the base. Now the pointer values will not match.